# not able to identify element textarea using protractor with typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor

textarea properties:

```
<div class="col-sm-11 no-padding-no-margin ng-star-inserted" _ngcontent-c18="">
<textarea class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" id="000000005G" _ngcontent-c18="" ng-reflect-name="000000005G"></textarea>
</div>
```

i tried with class, id and xpath(//*[@id="0000000005"])

```
expect<any>(element(by.id('000000005G')).isDisplayed()).toBe(true)

element(by.className('form-control ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched')).sendKeys('ABCD')

element(by.xpath('//*[@id="0000000005G"]')).sendKeys('ABCD')
```

Comment: The locator seems to be pretty straight forward. What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with just `tagName`?:

```
element(by.tagName('textarea'));
```

If it doesn't work, try with `css`:

```
element(by.css('.form-control.ng-pristine.ng-valid.ng-touched'));
```

Comment: i tried above options but not able to identify. The page is developed using reactive forms.